# How do you make flashbacks especially obvious with a clear beginning and end?

Tags: creative-writing, comics

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kk7qB_GfNnY

Let's say the flashback flashes in the protagonist's mind, what can you do besides graying the gutters, or graying the panels, or making the borders fuzzy? Is there a way to make it clear where the end and beginning is, and convey that the thoughts are violently flashing inside the mind of the protagonist? I couldn't find anything beside what's explained in the video.

Comment: "graying the gutters, or graying the panels, or making the borders fuzzy" - you listed three ways to do it already...I'm curious why none of these three work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the length. If it is an extremely long flashback, then you would want to use a new chapter that begins with italics. For example:

> ### Chapter Two
>
> *Fifteen years ago:*
> I stood above the bodies of my parents, the room filled with a red haze.

Another way, if the flashback is short is to just use italics in a new paragraph. For example:

> I looked around the apartment and saw that is was similar to a place that I had lived before.
>
> *"Jerry! Jerry!" My mom called out as she came out of the kitchen from our small one bedroom apartment*

Comment: The question is tagged "comics". Is your answer about comics or regular novel writing? (Also, please don't use code syntax.)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to label them.  "Fifteen years ago."  "Current day."  etc.